# Monitor in netscaler with credentials

Tags: monitoring, health-monitoring, netscaler

I need to create a monitor in netscaler to check the health of a service. Regularly, I check the health of my service using a URL:

http://myserver01:9090/myapp-restfulws/admin/views/ping_query_view

That returns a 200 code if it is up and running. I can send that same query to every server in my cluster.

Normally, when I enter this URL in my browser, it prompts me for authentication. I enter my user name and password (my administrators credentials) and it works. That is the part I am not sure how to set up in Netscaler.  What type of monitor do I need and where in the monitor settings do I enter the credentials?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fun question that needs a little creativity to fix. Without making changes to the backend you have 2 options:

- Option A: create a user custom monitor. You can check the examples on /netscaler/monitors for WebInterface (nswi.pl) and StoreFront (nssf.pl). These 2 articles will help you https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123661 and https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX227727
- Option B: follow the article https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX117142

There is the possibility of a 3rd option but that is too complicated and I believe the ones above suffice.